# 'For loop' isn't creating modified copies of existing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I would like to create modified copies of dataframes (copies with only certain columns) with new names (in this example `df1_m`, `df2_m`, etc.) that I have loaded in my Jupyter notebook. But for some reason, the following code is producing empty tables when I try to print the copy dfs with new names. When I try to do this with code inside the loop on its own, it works. So placing this code in a for loop is causing come issue for some reason. What could be going wrong?

This is the 'for loop' code that doesn't work/produces empty dfs:

```
parameter_cols = [col1, col2, col3]

df1_m = pd.DataFrame()
df2_m = pd.DataFrame()
df3_m = pd.DataFrame()
df4_m = pd.DataFrame()
df5_m = pd.DataFrame()
df6_m = pd.DataFrame()

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
df_m_list = [df1_m, df2_m, df3_m, df4_m, df5_m, df6_m]
year_list = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

for df, df_m, yr in zip(df_list, df_m_list, year_list):
    df_m = df[parameter_cols]
    df_m = df_m.assign(year = yr)
```

However the same code outside the loop works and produces a the desired copy df (df1_m):

```
df1_m = df1[parameter_cols]
df1_m = df1_m.assign(year=2015)
```

Why is this?

Comment: While this looks like a really bad idea overall, you're probably trying to use a for loop on the `range(len(df_list))` or something like that and reference your lists by index inside your loop.  The way you have it now you are creating a new df called `df_m` and repeatedly overwriting it.

Comment: @Chris Even with numerous dataframes, is it best practice to do this with them individually without a loop? You said it's a bad idea, but I thought it was better code practice to try to condense code as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

`df_m = df[parameter_cols]` simply changes the local pointer, not the referenced variable. This would do the thing:

```
for i, yr in enumerate(year_list):
    df_m = df_list[i][parameter_cols]
    df_m_list[i] = df_m.assign(year = yr)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like the `df_m_list[i]` in the loop is assigning the `[i]` list element as the new name for dataframe copy. If I print `df1_m` for example, it's still empty. If I replace `df_m_list[i]` with `x` and print it, it prints the last table iterated over.

Answer (score 1):

Your setups seem a bit overkill. You can do forget about `df1_m`,.... Since `df.assign` creates a copy by default, you can just do:

```
parameter_cols = [col1, col2, col3]
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6]
year_list = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]

df_m_list = [d[parameter_cols].assign(year=y) 
                for d, y in zip(df_list, year_list)
            ]
```

Comment: The idea is to assign the new copies certain names, that's why there's a df_m_list. In the list comprehension suggested, is there a way to arrange each iteration to be assigned to a certain name in an existing list (in my example df_m_list with names df1_m, df2_m)?